# Method with generic collection parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i have a method, which should accept collection (perhaps `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>`) of any type (e.g. `List<int>` or `List<string>`).

inside of method i need to iterate collection and each element convert to string and add them together into one final string, like:

```
"(12, 123, 22)"
```

Problem is how to define that parameter collection can be of any type. I guess this is something about generics, but i do not know much about it.

However, i thing method definition should look something like this:

```
public string myMethod(List<T> list) { }
```

However, compiler does not allow it. Can you please tell me correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A
{
    public string myMethod<T>(List<T> list) { }
}
```

or

```
class B<T>
{
    public string myMethod(List<T> list) { }
}
```

---

Probably you may want to use `IEnumerable<T>` because you need just to enumerate over the sequence.

---

The same you can achieve using built-in functions:

```
IEnumerable<X> input = new List<X> { new X(), new X() };
IEnumerable<string> s = list.Select(x => x.ToString());
string result = String.Join(", ", s); // "x, x"
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx).

Comment: Thank you,works great. But i have a problem. Sometimes i need to pass null instead of List<T>. When i try it, it is nott possible. I get compiler error: Error 3 The type arguments for method 'MainWCFRole.DB.TrackDAO.getTracks<T>(string, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Vojtech: Try to cast: `(List<X>)null`